# Convert Python 2 sorted list of tuples to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, python-2.x

I'm converting some code from Python 2 to Python 3. I have a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a tuple of numbers and a set of numbers. Here's a small example:

```
l1_python2 = [
    ((8, 6), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((8, 7), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((0, 3), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 4), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 5), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 6), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 7), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 8), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((1, 0), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((8, 8), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 3), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 4), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 5), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 6), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
]

l1_python3 = [
    ((8, 6), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((8, 7), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((0, 3), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((0, 4), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((0, 5), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((0, 6), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((0, 7), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((0, 8), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((1, 0), {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}),
    ((8, 8), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((5, 3), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((5, 4), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((5, 5), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
    ((5, 6), {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}),
]
```

The code to sort in Python 2 is the following:

```
l1_python2.sort(
    lambda a, b: len(a[1]) > len(b[1])
    and 1
    or len(a[1]) < len(b[1])
    and -1
    or a[0] > b[0]
    and 1
    or a[1] < b[1]
    and -1
    or 0
)
```

The resulting sorted list is:

```
[
    ((0, 3), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 4), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 5), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 6), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 7), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((0, 8), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((1, 0), Set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])),
    ((8, 6), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((8, 7), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((8, 8), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 3), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 4), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 5), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
    ((5, 6), Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
]
```

I understand (or think that I do) that's it sorting by the length of the sets and by set comparison. I've been trying to convert to Python 3 with no luck though. I tried this first:

```
l1_python3.sort(
    key=(
        lambda a, b: len(a[1]) > len(b[1])
        and 1
        or len(a[1]) < len(b[1])
        and -1
        or a[0] > b[0]
        and 1
        or a[1] < b[1]
        and -1
        or 0
    )
)
```

That gives an error that it's missing one required positional argument b, which makes sense. I then tried this:

```
l1_python3.sort(
key=(
    lambda a: len(a[0][1]) > len(a[1][1])
    and 1
    or len(a[0][1]) < len(a[1][1])
    and -1
    or a[0][1] > a[1][1]
    and 1
    or a[0][1] < a[1][1]
    and -1
    or 0
)
```

)

But that returns a TypeError that object of type 'int' has no len(). I've tried a few other things also but they usually don't sort at all. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate They actually do since in Python `and` and `or` returns the last operand (or something like that),  not always `True`/`False`. so it returns -1, 1 or 0 depending on the other operands

Comment: @Holt I'm aware of shortcircuiting, but the sort `key` parameter doesn't accept 1,-1,0 as returns afaik. It expects a boolean, in which case `1`, `-1`, and `True` are the same. It's a comparator that accepts signed numbers, but that's distinct.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ah, yes, but then you should say that you're talking of the Python 3 version because in the Python 2 version, it's using a comparator (I guess).

Comment: @Holt That may be true. I don't have enough experience with 2, and might explain difference of behavior (Edit: 2's `sort` has a `cmp` parameter that accepts the alternate behavior).

Comment: Python 2 `sort()` expects as `cmp` a function that accepts 2 values and returns `-1`, `0`, `1` depending on which is greater. Python 3 expects as `key()` a function that accepts one value and returns the value it should be sorted by. There is a recipe by Raymond HeItinger on bytes.com for converting the one to the other. Google `python cmp2key`. There is something similar in the `functools` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird lambda is actually a convoluted way of saying:

- 1 if `len(a[0][1]) > len(a[1][1])`
- -1 if `len(a[0][1]) < len(a[1][1])`
- otherwise

  - 1 if `a[0][1] > a[1][1]`
  - -1 if `a[0][1] < a[1][1]`
  - else `0`

So you first want to compare length of elements then theirs values (if length are equals), so your key needs to be something like:

```
l1_python3.sort(
  key=lambda a: (len(a[1]), a[1])
)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did what I wanted. Thanks for explaining too what was going on. I didn't understand it as much as I thought I did.